# GWT Highchart comparing series

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I am using Highstock with the `GWT` wrapper from [org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwt-highcharts/)

In the offical API of highchart, there is an option i can set to compare data series.

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        compare: 'percent'
    }
},
```

Once that set, I can access the percentage change in the tooltips through the variable `{point.change}`

I am wondering how do i get access of the variable `{point.change}` through the `ToolTipFormatter`. (may be in the `ToolTipData` object?)

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you reproduce your example in jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a way to do this is to use setPointFormat instead of ToolTipData

Example below:

```
StringBuffer point = new StringBuffer();
point.append("<tr style=\"height : 15px;\"><td style=\"height : 15px;font-weight:bold; font-size: 11px; padding-right:5px; color:{series.color}\">{series.name}:</td>");
point.append("<td style=\"height : 15px; font-size: 11px; color: black; text-align: right\">{point.y:.2f} ({point.change}%)</td></tr>");

chart.setToolTip(
        new ToolTip()
                .setShared(true)
                .setCrosshairs(true)
                .setUseHTML(true)
                .setOption("yDecimals", 2)
                .setOption("xDateFormat", "%d-%b-%Y")
                .setOption(
                        "headerFormat",
                        "<span style=\"font-size: 12px; font-weight:bold;\">{point.key}</span><br/><table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">")
                .setPointFormat(point.toString()))
                .setOption("footerFormat", "</table>");
```